# Node npm start - cannot find module 'mongodb'

Tags: node-mongodb-native

I was following the Christopher Buechler tutorial (http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/)for getting started with Node/Express/MongoDB. I made it to Step 6 where where I'm trying to display the userlist on the local host but I can't get npm start to work.

When I do npm start it says 
cannot find module 'mongodb'

As per one helpful person in the comments:
 I had to do npm install mongo --save and npm install monk --save

but this has not helped npm start to work.

What's next? I retraced my footsteps to make sure I haven't missed anything.
Here is what my command line says:

C:\node>cd nodetest1

C:\node\nodetest1>npm start

> nodetest1@0.0.1 start C:\node\nodetest1
>   node ./bin/www

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (C:\node\nodetest1\app.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

npm ERR! nodetest1@0.0.1 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodetest1@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the nodetest1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodetest1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program File
s (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd C:\node\nodetest1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\node\nodetest1\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\node\nodetest1>

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `npm install mongodb`

Comment: AMAZING! One little detail. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: I'd love to. Clearly I'm blind because I don't see where/how to do that. I've been on stack overflow a short time and I haven't been given that privilege yet. One day when I have it I'll come back and vote you up!